# Angular 2 routing for master detail responsive page

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I am looking for a way to have different routing for mobile and desktop resolution. I have mater detail page layout. So when the user moves to mobile, user should see master list & when user clicks item of the list, it should navigate to the details page. I am thinking there will be 2 sets of routes for desktop and mobile & I will need to load correct route config based on width.

Please suggest.

For desktop:

```
  const appDesktopRoutes:Routes =[
         {
            path: '',
            component: ItemListComponent,
            children: [
                {
                    path: 'item/:id',
                    component: ItemDetailsComponent
                }
            ]
        }]
```

For Mobile :

```js
const appMobileRoutes:Routes =[
    {
        path: '',
        component: ItemListComponent,
    },
     {
        path: 'item/:id',
        component: ItemDetailsComponent
    }
]
```

Comment: did the updated solution work for you?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the width of your window like below, Once you have them you can use it to hide your detail component in template, and update your detail list click behaviour, to navigate rather opening in the same page.

```
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(ngZone: NgZone) {
    // Initial draw
    this.drawPage(window.innerWidth);
   
    // On resize
    window.onresize = (e) => {
      ngZone.run(() => {
       this.drawPage(window.innerWidth);
      });
    };
  }

  drawPage(width){
    // use width to determine how to draw.
  }
}
```

**Update:**

You need to reset routes based on the width.

try below,

create a Resolution service which can give you window width,

**ResolutionService**

```
@Injectable()
export class ResolutionService {
  constructor(ngZone: NgZone) {
    // On resize
    window.onresize = (e) => {
      ngZone.run(() => {
        this.width.next(window.innerWidth);
      });
    };
  }

  width: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject<number>(window.innerWidth);
}
```

Use above service in your RouterModule to reset route like below,

**AppRoutingModule**

```
const appDesktopRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ItemListComponent,
    children: [
      {
        path: 'item/:id',
        component: ItemDetailsComponent
      }
    ]
  }
];

const appMobileRoutes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: ItemListComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'item/:id',
    component: ItemDetailsComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appDesktopRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {
  MOBILE_WIDTH = 500;
  constructor(router: Router, resolutionService: ResolutionService) {

    // subscribe to resolution service to get current width
    resolutionService.width.subscribe(width => {
      if (width < this.MOBILE_WIDTH) {
        router.resetConfig(appMobileRoutes);
      } else {
        router.resetConfig(appDesktopRoutes);
      }
    });

  }
}
```

Here is the [example Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/yi36hEwmiNMEP6kxCKOd?p=preview)!!

Comment: to navigate rather opening in the same page. ? I am stuck on this. For desktop, i will have details state as a child of the master state. But for mobile,  I need routes as a flat array so that it can open detail in new page

Comment: Can you add how you are showing different detail when you are clicking on the master list, i am assuming you must be having some click event which would get the detail and bind to your detail component. So you may have some logic when clicked to navigate to the detail route instead of showing in the detail component when the width is right, cheers!!

Comment: gotoItemDetails(id) {this.router.navigate(['/myItems/item',id]);}

Comment: yes, so you can easily have it wrapped using width, something like, gotoItemDetails(id) { if(this.width < 400) { this.router.navigate(['/myItems/item',id]);} else{ // show it here...}}, Cheers!!

Comment: thanks for the solution. But I will be using this kind of routing across the project which will have multiple feature modules. So wanted to do this routing at a high level so feature modules don't need to check the width.

Comment: Any idea about it ?

Comment: if you can update your question with relevaant code what you have, then i may help.

Comment: @iAmitWagh, I have updated my answer based on your update, Also added a Plunker with example. Hope it helps, Cheers!!